# Exporting Report From VB.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, csv, export

Is there a way to export data that has been populated into a VB.net forms application split by Tabs? I have a large program that connects to a SQL database and runs many queries to populate Labels within the application.

I would like to export the data into an Excel Sheet over different tabs per Tabular Page in the Form application. If this is not possible then a generic .csv export will be fine.

I am running my SQL query and importing it into Labels like this -

```
Dim myCmd23 As New SqlCommand("MySQL Query", myconn)
    Dim myDataA23 As New SqlDataAdapter(myCmd23)
    Dim myDataT23 As New DataTable()
    Dim myDataS23 As New DataSet()

    myDataA23.Fill(myDataT23)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDataT23

    Dim result23(2) As String

    result23(1) = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
    result23(2) = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString

    Label1.Text = result23(1)
    Label2.Text = result23(2)
```

There are many of these SqlCommands carried out. The Form application looks like such -

[image: Form Application]

The seperate tabs are shown above and i would like to try and seperate this data in the Export?

The Dates and Filters are taken into account within each seperate SQL query so they are no bother.

If anybody has a possible solution that would be great.

Thanks

Greg

Answer (score 0):

There are several blogs about exporting datatables to Excel in VB.NET [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/1693-cache-cow/)